# Onchange attribute in select is not getting triggered in codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter, in this particular form I have triggered chain ajax to populate students class wise and subsequently fee status of selected student. The first ajax to populate student from selected class is working properly however after selecting student onchange is not getting triggered.
To check if the function is working correctly I've included a span with onclick and confirmed that function is returning value.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('class');?></label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <select name="class_id"
            class="form-control"
            onchange="return get_annual_fee(this.value), get_quarterly_fee(this.value),get_exam_fee(this.value), get_class_students(this.value)">
      <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select_class');?></option>
      <?php $classes = $this->db->get('class')->result_array();
            foreach ($classes as $row): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['class_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
      <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('student');?></label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <select name="student_id"
            id="student_selection_holder"
            class="form-control"
            style="width:100%;"
            onchange="status(this.value)">
      <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select_class');?></option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <span onclick="return status('this.value')">Click Here To Load Status</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can call up a single method which would internally callup the methods which you specified

onchange="return get_annual_fee(this.value), get_quarterly_fee(this.value),get_exam_fee(this.value), get_class_students(this.value)"

can be 

`onchange="foo(this)"`

and 
`function foo(that){
 get_annual_fee(that.value), get_quarterly_fee(that.value)
,get_exam_fee(that.value), get_class_students(that.value)
}`

Comment: Thanks sandeep but my problem is in the other select with name student_id. The first one mentioned in your comment is working fine.

Comment: can you pls share the js code for more idea?